# Checkout Submission problems with Order notes & Custom Attributes

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-storefront-api

My basic problem is I have a script that creates cart attributes & also adds them to the shopify cart.

That way if the cart note doesn't submit the attributes will have a record of the selected options.

Now my issue is the cart note doesn't submit to the order even though I can clearly see it in the cart.js

This is a cut down of the the cart.js

```
{
 "token":"Z2NwLXVzLWVhc3QxOjAxSFA1QjQ1RjkzUkFCQVI2MEoyRThUVFZX",
 "note":"ATL-At the front door","attributes":
 {"Getting your delivery":"ATL",
  "Choose a safe location to leave your delivery.":"At the front door"
 },
}
```

Am I missing something ie. you can't submit a cart note & attributes together etc?